# How to get "Long" values without rounding error using influxdb-java.jar?

Tags: java, influxdb

I wrote a data using influx command (CLI) as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
USE mydb
insert test value=1234567890123456789i
```

Then, I read the data using influx command (CLI)

```
> select * from test
name: test
time                    value
1475129299322514085     1234567890123456789
```

OK. No Problem.

But when I read the data using a JAVA program with influxdb-java-2.3.jar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    InfluxDB conn = InfluxDBFactory.connect(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD);
    String sql =  "SELECT time,value from test";
    Query query = new Query(sql, DB_NAME);
    QueryResult result = conn.query(query, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    Series series = result.getResults().get(0).getSeries().get(0);

    System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(0) + "=" + series.getValues().get(0).get(0) + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(0).getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(1) + "=" + series.getValues().get(0).get(1) + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(1).getClass().getName());
}
```

The result is:

```
time=1.47512929932251418E18 java.lang.Double
value=1.23456789012345677E18 java.lang.Double
```

Why was *"time"* returned in *"Double"* even though the query option was NANOSECONDS?

Why was *"value"* returned in *"Double"*  even though the data was inserted with "i" suffix?

The "value" I am expecting is *1234567890123456789*, not *1234567890123456770* *(=1.23456789012345677E18)*.

How will I be able to get "Long" values without rounding error using influxdb-java.jar?

Comment: Have you brought up this issue with the project team over on GitHub? (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb)

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment. This is the correct link to the java client: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use MSGPACK Format, on influxdb-java-2.15.jar

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
InfluxDB jsonInfluxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(URL, USER, PASSWORD, client, ResponseFormat.JSON);
InfluxDB msgpackInfluxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(URL, USER, PASSWORD, client, ResponseFormat.MSGPACK);
//influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.FULL);
Query query = new Query("SELECT * FROM xxx LIMIT 1", "XXX");

QueryResult jsonResult = jsonInfluxDB.query(query, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
logger.info("{}", jsonResult);

QueryResult msgpackResult = msgpackInfluxDB.query(query, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
logger.info("{}", msgpackResult);
```

Result

```
INFO test - QueryResult [results=[Result [series=[Series [name=mib, tags=null, columns=[time, commodity, country, expiration, high, indicator, instrument, last, low, market, modifier, open, strike, turnover, volume], values=[[1.56937620100001485E18, 300, 96, 20191213, 1.621E7, =, 11, 1.6145E7, 1.592E7, 60, 0, 1.6E7, 0, 55640.0, 2.0]]]], error=null]], error=null]
INFO test - QueryResult [results=[Result [series=[Series [name=mib, tags=null, columns=[time, commodity, country, expiration, high, indicator, instrument, last, low, market, modifier, open, strike, turnover, volume], values=[[1569376201000014846, 300, 96, 20191213, 16210000, =, 11, 16145000, 15920000, 60, 0, 16000000, 0, 55640, 2]]]], error=null]], error=null]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no proper solution for you. This library designed that way.

Workaround is to cast to `long`:

```
System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(0) + "=" + (long)(double)series.getValues().get(0).get(0) + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(0).getClass().getName());
```

or

```
System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(1) + "=" + series.getValues().get(0).get(1).longValue() + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(1).getClass().getName());
```

Comment: I made a suggestion to bring it up to the project team. Which this project alone has 393 open issues... I think I've found my next GitHub project

Comment: cannot be cast to Double to long (java.lang.ClassCastException)

Comment: `((Number)series.getValues().get(0).get(1)).longValue() ` =1234567890123456768 (not 1234567890123456789)